# Difference in the log while firing the same query again in solr with tomcat

Tags: search, tomcat, solr, http-headers

When I querying the same string again in solr, I am not getting the response time. I am getting the following error in the log.

Oct 08, 2013 1:53:34 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

However, for the first query of the string ,it works fine. Please help me.

Comment: Your HTTP request is apparently invalid. What does it look like? What version of Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might actually be the malformed **client** request, rather than the server one. Try to get hold of specific request from the client and see what the HTTP headers look like. Perhaps switch Tomcat logging level to DEBUG to see further details.